# Delayed 'math processing error' in mathjax

Tags: mathjax

My mathjax equation renders correctly, but after about 30 seconds, the rendered equation goes away and a 'math processing error' appears. Is it related to math-preview?

I tested the mathjax code in the mathjax dynamic tester and it worked fine, so I don't think it is the code.and yet the error appears.

I am using a left-align display command in my config file

MathJax.Hub.Config({
    jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
    showMathMenu: false,
    displayAlign: "left",  displayIndent:"2em"

});

which might be related, because when the equations first render, they are centered, but then I get the math processing error. The problem is intermittent, and when the problem isnot occurring, then the equations correctly justifies to the left after a few seconds.

my mathjax appears below. Thanks for any help.

```
<script id="MathJax-Element-1" type="math/tex; mode=display">
\begin{align}
μ &= {\sum X \over N} \cr
&={(1+2+3+4+5+6+7) \over 7}\cr
&={28 \over 7}\cr
&=4
\end{align}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you add a self-contained example, ie a full page with MathJax configuration, loading etc?

Comment: You should not include the `id="MathJax-Element-1" on the script, as MathJax will add that itself.  Without a full page, as Peter requests, it is hard to tell. For instance, you haven't given the script tag that loads MathJax.js, and so we can't tell what config file you are using, or whether you are using the CDN or hosting your own copy.

Comment: The 30 second delay is probably due to MathJax not being able to load one of its components.  Use `MathJax.Message.Log()` in the browser console to find out what files aren't being loaded, and report those here.